# Run an influxdb image offline

Tags: docker, local, influxdb

I work on a web app that uses data from an influxdb stored on a server. I now want to make this app available offline and I'm looking for a way to save on demand a copy of this database on the user's computer, so that he could run this copy on a local host (and sync it as soon as he reconnects).

Does anyone has any idea of a good way to implement that ? (i.e, that requires a simple procedure from the user point of vue). I had a look on Docker but I'm not sure if I really need it. But if so, is there also a way to run Dockers config commands within the app script or should the user download Docker and type these commands himself ?

Thanks for your help !

[EDIT] Finally, I managed to do that for the influxdb using tutum/influxdb. I only had to install Docker, follow [this instructions](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/influxdb/) and add a script in the app to copy data from the server to the client db. Now I think I will have to do something similar for the server scripts I need to keep offline...

Comment: Have you looked into any of the data storage mechanisms that HTML5 provides?  Maybe you should be caching on the client side to one of those and committing to influxdb when connectivity is restored.

Comment: Are we talking about `web app` or `desktop application` here? There is a difference. `Web app` is supposed to be a lightweight client running on a browser as opposed to the standard application where sometimes you can have a small db like `sqlite` baked into it. If it is a `web app` then it doesn't make sense to make the end user install `influx`. What @axlj suggested is worth considering.

Comment: This is indeed a web app based on Meteor, but I need to keep some server methods and a "sample" of the database available offline. But, as far as I know, a cache can only save client side script. This is why I wanted to run a kind of "virtual machine" with Docker that I could use like a server.